# Get more detail information on AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, upgrade, access-violation, .net-8.0

I have an application that contains of hundreds of C# (main app) and some C++ projects.
We are using .NET 6 and it is working fine. until recently I would like to try to upgrade to .NET 8 and I got System.AccessViolationException without much information to know the detail information (stack trace, code/method that call it, etc). I have no idea how to track the cause of this because the scope area is too big.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Unknown Module.
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Additional information:

- I have tried to upgrade to .NET 7 and it is working just fine. So only .NET 8 have this issue
- I have upgraded my VS to latest version and microsoft edge (it shares dll with webview2 if not mistaken)
- I have updated my nuget packages to the latest

Question:
What can I do to help me track the cause of this exception and makes it running well as in previous .NET version (6.0 and 7.0)?

Thanks

Comment: There is a "copy details" link in that dialog. Click it. Paste in your question via an [edit] to replace the screenshot.

Comment: See [Collect dump on crash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/collect-dumps-crash). If you can get a crash dump it should help investigate the problem.

Comment: It might help to check the Windows Event Viewer. It usually records a crash like this and might have some more information. Also you could check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/8.0) page. It lists all breaking changes in .NET8.